# Open GNU Screen with multiple windows

Tags: linux, bash, sh, gnu-screen

How to create a script that runs gnu screen with multiple windows, each window runs a command
For example

window 1 runs `python3 -m http.server`

window 2 runs `webpack --watch`

a screen with 2 windows start when I run script `./start.sh`

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question, and belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @tink thank you, I editted the question

Comment: google search for "screenrc examples" will be useful

Comment: That still doesn't make it a programming question; it's about how to use screen.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myselft, make a .screenrc file like this

```
startup_message off
caption always "%{= kw} %-w%{= gW} %n %t %{-}%+w %-="
screen -t http  ./scripts/serve.sh
screen -t watch ./scripts/watch.sh
```

then run screen -c .screenrc